# How to displayUITableView indexPath.row in Xcode lldb console window

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

How do you print out a UITables indexPath.row in the console window.
I dont want to add NSLogs everywhere.

I keep getting 'is not a member' or property.

```
(lldb) expr (int) printf("%d \n",self.lastChangedIndexPath->_row)
error: 'NSIndexPath' does not have a member named '_row'


(lldb) print self.lastChangedIndexPath->_row
error: 'NSIndexPath' does not have a member named '_row'


(lldb) print self.lastChangedIndexPath->row
error: 'NSIndexPath' does not have a member named 'row'


(lldb) print self.lastChangedIndexPath.row
error: property 'row' not found on object of type 'NSIndexPath *'


(lldb) po  self.lastChangedIndexPath.row
error: property 'row' not found on object of type 'NSIndexPath *'
```

I think because row and section are in a UITableView category:

```
@interface NSIndexPath (UITableView)

+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSInteger)row inSection:(NSInteger)section;

@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger section;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger row;

@end
```

I even created a mini test app and created a clone of NSIndexPath called MyIndexPath and I can access it ok using:

```
(lldb) print self.indexPath->_row
(NSInteger) $0 = 10
(lldb) print self.indexPath.row
(NSInteger) $1 = 10
(lldb)
```

TEST app

```
#import "ViewController.h"    



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CLONE OF NSIndexPath ===================================
#pragma mark -
//------ a clone on NSindexPath with same section and row properties
@interface MyIndexPath : NSObject
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger section;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger row;

@end
@implementation MyIndexPath
@end



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MAIN CLASS that has MyIndexPath as iVar =============================
#pragma mark -

@interface ViewController (){
    NSString * _iVarString;
    int        _iVarInt;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  * propertyString;
@property (nonatomic        ) NSInteger   propertyInt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyIndexPath * indexPath;
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Set iVars
    _iVarString = @"hello ivar";
    _iVarInt = 34;

    //Set properties (and synthesized ivars _propertyString and _propertyInt)
    self.propertyString = @"my propertyString";
    self.propertyInt    = 46;

    //Local vars
    NSString * localString_ = @"hello";
    int        localInt_    = 10;

    //------
    self.indexPath = [[MyIndexPath alloc]init];
    self.indexPath.section = 10;
    self.indexPath.row = 10;


    NSLog(@"PUT BREAKPOINT HERE");

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And I can access it fine - just not in a UITableView category.

```
(lldb) print self.indexPath->_row
(NSInteger) $0 = 10
(lldb) print self.indexPath.row
(NSInteger) $1 = 10
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If lldb does not know about a property then you can always use the accessor function:

```
print (NSInteger) [self.lastChangedIndexPath row]
```

Comment: excellent... would help if I read the comment in the error. "cast the message send to the method's return type" 
Why doesnt print [self.lastChangedIndexPath row] work thats accessing the accessor too.

Answer (score 13):

You can make Xcode show the indexpath in the variables window by doubletapping on an nsindexpath variable and setting the following summary format:

```
section:{(int)[$VAR section]},row:{(int)[$VAR row]}
```